# \r mangles variable assignment in python

Tags: python

I have a very unusual problem. Am working with python 2.6 to make API calls to a bulkSMS gateway. Now if I make the call like this

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

I get this(correct) response printed back to terminal

```
'<RESPONSE>\r<status>-4</status>\r<credits>31.3403</credits>\r</RESPONSE>'
```

But when I assign this output to variable,

```
reply = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

I get this(incorrect) response when I print to terminal

```
print reply
</RESPONSE>.3403</credits>
```

Anybody care to explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is interpreting the `\r` characters as a special character (ASCII carriage return - see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for some examples) and removing them from the string on printing. To include them, you can use the `string-escape` encoding:

```
In [1]: resp = '<RESPONSE>\r<status>-4</status>\r<credits>31.3403</credits>\r</RESPONSE>'

In [2]: print resp
</RESPONSE>.3403</credits>

In [3]: print resp.encode('string-escape')
<RESPONSE>\r<status>-4</status>\r<credits>31.3403</credits>\r</RESPONSE>
```

Not directly applicable in your case, but another way this kind of escaping is done is to prefix a string with `r`, which makes it a 'raw' string and keeps the backslashes (you'll see this a lot with regular expression):

```
In [4]: resp = r'<RESPONSE>\r<status>-4</status>\r<credits>31.3403</credits>\r</RESPONSE>'

In [5]: print resp
<RESPONSE>\r<status>-4</status>\r<credits>31.3403</credits>\r</RESPONSE>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, while still preserving the content of the variable in it's original form.

Comment: @user1048839 Awesome, glad it worked out for you. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 2):

The string contains the correct data, it's just printing in a weird way.  `\r` is a carriage return, which some systems interpret as "go back to the beginning of the line and start overwriting from there".  So you see `"</RESPONSE>"` plus data from the previous line that was longer (and so wasn't overwritten).

It's a bit odd that your data contain `\r` since it's not that common as a line-ending convention these days.

You could print `repr(response)` to see the response without `\r` interpreted this way.  Any processing you do on the line should work fine since all the data is there, it's just not printing.

Comment: +1 - good point about the resetting of the position back to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly the issue. If necessary, you can fix the string with `reply.replace("\r", "\n")`, which will put newlines in place of the carriage returns.

Comment: Am very tempted to replace the offending character 'r' but that would essentially mean changing the content of the reply which I would like to stay as close to original as possible since I will be using it across other functions too.